# How to resolve "ReferenceError: $ is not defined"?

Tags: angular

I am trying to use jquery in angular2 and got this error: ReferenceError: $ is not defined from the following code.

declare var $:JQueryStatic;

```
export class AppComponent {    

ngOnInit() {    

    var container = $("#contact-us-form");    

    container.css("width", $(document).width()).css("height", $(document).height()).hide();    

    container.find(".modal-content .button-close").click(function(){ this.toggleModalWindow("contact-us-form"); });    

    $("#contact-link").click(function(){ this.toggleModalWindow("contact-us-form"); });    

   }     
}
```

How could I resolve this ?

Comment: /*Jquery is installed using typings install dt~jquery --global --save. Getting error in var container = $("#contact-us-form"); line saying that $ is not defined. */

Comment: Could you explain the purpose of the declaration `declare var $:JQueryStatic;`?

Comment: I want to use $.. So. In fact I want to write jquery stuffs

Comment: Well... `$` is a very special character both for Angular and JQuery. Try using some other variable name and see if you still get the error.

Comment: I just used 'Jq', n i am getting 'Jq is not defined in [null]'

Comment: You sample code does not show much. Is the variable defined within the context of a function? Did you try without the `declare`? If you want a variable with global scope, just use it without `var` like: `myVar = {} ;`

Comment: Tried removing the declare. Still its same :(

Comment: Ran out of ideas. Sorry.

Comment: Please tell me.. How can I use Jquery in angular2.. Bcz, whatever I tried its not working for me

Comment: You should try this answer, worked well for Angular 10 https://stackoverflow.com/a/45573919/11156666

Answer (score 4):

add angular-cli.json

```
 "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
```

Have a typescript file

```
  import * as $ from "jquery";
```

install jquery using npm

Answer (score 4):

FOLLOW THESE STEPS:

1. `npm i jquery --save`
2. `npm i @types/jquery -D`
3. `import * as $ from 'jquery'`---> *in app.module.ts*

That should do the trick and no need to put `declare var jQuery: any;` or `declare var $: any;` in each file.

Comment: Steps are working. Please add some comments with steps to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Try these Steps-

1. npm install jquery @types/jquery --save
2. go to angular.json in the project, add 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js' in the scripts: [ ].
3. Reload project.